# Wait for popen script to terminate in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, popen

Is that possible with C to wait until the popen subprocess is finished?

I have a script launched by a C daemon which will connect to a wifi network when an external signal is triggered.

Here is my code for now :

```
********************* Wait for external event here ***********************

if((fp = popen(CONNECTION_SCRIPT, "r")) == NULL)
{
    SYSLOG_ERR("[Error] Impossible to open pipe to execute  %s\n", CONNECTION_SCRIPT);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while(fgets(scriptBuffer, SCRIPT_BUF_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
{
    SYSLOG("[%s] %s", CONNECTION_SCRIPT, scriptBuffer);
}

if(pclose(fp))
{
    SYSLOG_ERR("[Error] Error with %s execution \n", CONNECTION_SCRIPT);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

However, I'm not waiting for the subprocess to finish so when I'm closing the pipe, the ressource is busy because the script is stil writting in.
Is there a way to wait for the end of the connection script before reading in the pipe and closing it?

I know I could do it by forking the process and waiting for the child to terminate but it's quite a lot of modifications just to synchronize threads

Comment: On the face of it, your code won't exit the `fgets()` loop until the script has closed the pipe that you're reading from, so you won't call `pclose()` until the script has finished.  That leaves open the question: what effect are you seeing exactly?  Can you produce an MCVE ([MCVE]) that reproduces your problem?  The SYSLOG and SYSLOG_ERR calls should probably be mapped to `printf()` or `fprintf()` in the MCVE.

Comment: The SYSLOG and SYSLOG_ERR are just formatted macro I defined in the top of the file. `#define SYSLOG(fmt, args...)  syslog(LOG_NOTICE, fmt, ## args);`
`#define SYSLOG_ERR(fmt, args...) syslog(LOG_ERR, fmt " : %s", ## args , strerror(errno));` and here is the log line `[Error] Error with sudo /usr/local/bin/wifi-disconnect.sh execution #012 : Device or resource busy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you say that you get a "resource busy" error because `errno` has the value `EBUSY` when you log the error in the third last line of your snippet. That may well be misleading.

In general, you should only check the value of `errno` if you have a solid indication that an error occurred. In the case of `pclose`, that indication would be that the function returns precisely -1 (and not any non-zero value, as is the case with your current code).

Any value other than -1 returned by `pclose` should be interpreted as the subprocess's termination code; in such a case, `errno` will have an unspecified (and therefore misleading) value. You can use the `WEXITSTATUS`, `WIFSIGNALED` and `WTERMSIG` macros as explained in the `waitpid` manpage to interpret the return value from `pclose`.

As documented in its manpage, `pclose` waits for the subprocess to terminate, so it already does what you request. It will return an actual error indication (-1) if its use of `waitpid` returns an error (unlikely, but anything is possible).

Comment: .... My bad, I didn't read pclose documentation with enough attention.
Indeed replacing `if(pclose(fp))` with `if(pclose(fp) == -1)` did the job.
I though pclose was not waiting for thread to terminate and was returning 0 on success
Thanks a lot